# retrieve the scheduled date of a sidekiq worker within it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Let's have a lot of jobs queued for a certain Date `my_date`.

There is so much job for this exact same date that some of them are working only 20 minutes after their scheduled_date.

How can I retrieve this scheduled date once I am in my `perform` method ?

ps : I can't pass this scheduled_date as params, because its a Cron job (and I can only pass static params)

ps2 : github issue https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3945

edit : for now here is a partial answer, still not satisfying (for exemple not working for a retry):

```
# wait for Sidekiq::Workers to be updated (5 sec)
sleep 8
the_exact_date = Time.at(Sidekiq::Workers.new.find { |_, __, w| w["payload"]["jid"] == jid }[2]["run_at"])
```

edit 2 : current PR for sidekiq cron which fully solve my issue : https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron/pulls

Comment: can you please explain how you solved this issue please? 
I am looking for the exact same problem, but I'm not using sidekiq-cron...

Comment: Hey @alex sorry for the delay, I submitted a PR some times ago that solves this issue : 

https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron/pull/221

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Sidekiq-cron :

I submitted a PR and it was accepted. The solution  is to use the optional `date_as_argument` param when initializing your sidekiq-cron job:

https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a `enqueued_at` mandatory argument passed to the job, which is I believe exactly what you are looking for.

If you are instead looking for the time when the job was started, it's simply `Time.current` at the beginning of the perform method.

See `https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Job-Format#job` for official documentation.

Comment: Thank you but into my job I have no access to this argument. Once in the worker, the job is already consumed, and so, no more in the Redis queue. Sadly the only params I have access to into my worker is jid. Of course I can retrieve the current Time, but this is not my point. I want to retrieve the original scheduled date regardless of the retries number or queue length.